# Google Vertex AI hyperparameter tuning: 500 Internal Error encountered

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I was trying to run a hyperparameter tuning job on Vertex AI using the Python SDK described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/using-hyperparameter-tuning#aiplatform_create_hyperparameter_tuning_job_python_package_sample-python). Around 2 hours ago it was successful sending the job to run. I noticed there are some errors in my code so the run failed, and I went back and fix it, and I re-run the code and what I got was as below.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.INTERNAL
        details = "Internal error encountered."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1623393121.374988331","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.251.33.74:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1066,"grpc_message":"Internal error encountered.","grpc_status":13}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/ariel_ml_2021/hparam_tuning.py", line 140, in <module>
    create_hyperparameter_tuning_job_python_package()
  File "/workspace/ariel_ml_2021/hparam_tuning.py", line 133, in create_hyperparameter_tuning_job_python_package
    response = client.create_hyperparameter_tuning_job(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1/services/job_service/client.py", line 1363, in create_hyperparameter_tuning_job
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 69, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Internal error encountered.
```

I thought this might be due to my changes in the python code that causes the error, so I try with the original copy (without making any changes), and the error persists. The code for hyperparameter tuning is as below if required.

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform


def create_hyperparameter_tuning_job_python_package(
    project: str = "<my_project_id>",
    display_name: str = "<some_description>",
    executor_image_uri: str = "us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-cpu.2-4:latest",
    package_uri: str = "gs://<bucket_name>/",
    python_module: str = "train_second",  # located at gs://<bucket_name>/train_second.py
    location: str = "us-central1",
    api_endpoint: str = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
):
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    client = aiplatform.gapic.JobServiceClient(client_options=client_options)

    metric = {
        "metric_id": "ariel_score",
        "goal": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.MetricSpec.GoalType.MAXIMIZE,
    }

    conditional_param_H1 = {
        "parameter_spec": {
            "parameter_id": "H1",
            "discrete_value_spec": {"values": [4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]},
            "scale_type": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.ParameterSpec.ScaleType.UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE,
        },
        "parent_discrete_values": {"values": [10, 25, 50, 100]}
    }

    conditional_param_H2 = {
        "parameter_spec": {
            "parameter_id": "H2",
            "discrete_value_spec": {"values": [64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]},
            "scale_type": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.ParameterSpec.ScaleType.UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE,
        },
        "parent_discrete_values": {"values": [10, 25, 50, 100]}
    }


    conditional_param_H3 = {
        "parameter_spec": {
            "parameter_id": "H3",
            "discrete_value_spec": {"values": [4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]},
            "scale_type": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.ParameterSpec.ScaleType.UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE,
        },
        "parent_discrete_values": {"values": [10, 25, 50, 100]}
    }

    conditional_param_D1 = {
        "parameter_spec": {
            "parameter_id": "D1",
            "double_value_spec": {"min_value": 0.01, "max_value": 0.5},
            "scale_type": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.ParameterSpec.ScaleType.UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE,
        },
        "parent_discrete_values": {"values": [10, 25, 50, 100]}
    }

    conditional_param_mean = {
        "parameter_spec": {
            "parameter_id": "mean",
            "discrete_value_spec": {"values": [0., 1.]},
            "scale_type": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.ParameterSpec.ScaleType.UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE,
        },
        "parent_discrete_values": {"values": [10, 25, 50, 100]}
    }

    conditional_param_std = {
        "parameter_spec": {
            "parameter_id": "std",
            "double_value_spec": {"min_value": 0.005, "max_value": 0.5},
            "scale_type": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.ParameterSpec.ScaleType.UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE,
        },
        "parent_discrete_values": {"values": [10, 25, 50, 100]}
    }

    conditional_param_lr = {
        "parameter_spec": {
            "parameter_id": "lr",
            "discrete_value_spec": {"values": [0.0001, 0.0003, 0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3]},
            "scale_type": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.ParameterSpec.ScaleType.UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE,
        },
        "parent_discrete_values": {"values": [10, 25, 50, 100]}
    }

    parameter = {
        "parameter_id": "batch_size",
        "discrete_value_spec": {"values": [10, 25, 50, 100]},
        "scale_type": aiplatform.gapic.StudySpec.ParameterSpec.ScaleType.UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE,
        "conditional_parameter_specs": [
            conditional_param_H1, 
            conditional_param_H2,
            conditional_param_H3,
            conditional_param_D1,
            conditional_param_mean,
            conditional_param_std,
            conditional_param_lr,
        ],
    }

    # Trial job spec
    machine_spec = {
        "machine_type": "e2-standard-4",
    }
    worker_pool_spec = {
        "machine_spec": machine_spec,
        "replica_count": 1, 
        "python_package_spec": {
            "executor_image_uri": executor_image_uri,
            "package_uris": [package_uri],
            "python_module": python_module,
            "args": [],
        }
    }

    # hparam tuning job
    hyperparameter_tuning_job = {
        "display_name": display_name,
        "max_trial_count": 2, 
        "parallel_trial_count": 2,
        "study_spec": {
            "metrics": [metric],
            "parameters": [parameter],
        },
        "trial_job_spec": {"worker_pool_specs": [worker_pool_spec]},
    }

    parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}"
    response = client.create_hyperparameter_tuning_job(
        parent=parent, hyperparameter_tuning_job=hyperparameter_tuning_job
    )
    print(f"response:", response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_hyperparameter_tuning_job_python_package()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the endpoint at us-central1 is experiencing the problem. The workaround is to use another endpoint such as with us-east1 and the problem is solved.

Comment: Any idea where to check the region status?

Answer (score 0):

Your `package_uri` is incorrect. It should point to a file containing the Python package (i.e. a tar.bz file with all the code), not a directory or a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error and spent a lot of time debugging as the error is not very clear. Turns out the service account should have the sufficient permission to read Artifact Registry tags i.e. `roles/artifactregistry.reader`

This github issue helped: https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/issues/2181#issuecomment-1621594750